# I can't figure out why there is a space between my webheader div and my header div?

Tags: css, html

Here is the relevant html code:

```
<div id="something"><img src="Images/guysonlycopy.jpg" alt="image" width="1200"     height="300" /></div>  
   <header>
<div id="title"><img     src="http://blog.flamingtext.com/blog/2013/08/29/flamingtext_com_1377801873_445376518.jpg" padding="15px" /></div>
```

My first div is the"something" and the second is "title" but they have a gap of about 5px between them which i don't want.

```
body {
font: normal .8em/1.5em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: #ebebeb;
    width: 1200px;
margin: 100px auto;
color: #666;
}

#wrapper {
background-color: #ccc;
margin: 0;
width: 1200px;
}

/* Header
--------------------------------------------*/

header {
background-color: #170a6e;
height: 100px;
width: 1200px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

header h1 {
font-size: 4.5em;
float: left;
margin: 20px;
padding: 5px;

}

#something {
text-align: center;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#title {
float: left;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-top: 11px;
}
```

That is the css. I want there to be no gap between the image and the second div.

Answer (score 2):

Images are [`inline` elements by default](http://dorayme.netweaver.com.au/alt/inlinePicWithDescenderSpace.html), which means they leave [descender space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender). To get rid of this and use them as `block` level elements, set `display: block;` on the image itself.